# PlayFramework 2.1: Helper Bootstrap checkbox

Tags: java, forms, checkbox, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm developing a "SignUp form" in PlayFramework 2.1 using BootStrap helper. 
I override the bootstrap helper for this:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)  
<div class="control-group @if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">  
  <label class="control-label" for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>  
  <div class="controls">@elements.input    
    @if(elements.hasErrors) { <p class="help-block">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</p> }  
  </div>  
</div>
```

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.jamesfaeldon.com/2012/05/01/using-twitter-bootstrap-horizontal-forms-in-play-framework-2-0/)

Now, it's creating form-horizontal corretly. But if I use helper to create a checkbox, my checkbox and label are not aligned. Look this image:

[image: Checkboxes]

The First Checkbox was created with helper and the second I coded:

```
<div class="control-group">
   <div class="controls">
       <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"> I accept 
       </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to generate the same HTML that I wrote (second checkbox).
I'm freaking out with the helpers! How can I align my checkboxes? I will always have to create my own helpers?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a space in front of `@elements.label`. It's just regular HTML.
Or in front of `@elements.errors.mkString(", ")` I'm not sure.

But I have also constructed a better fieldConstructor where you can use prepended input as icons and letters and other features. You can use this and normally it will do everything you like and more.

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

@**************************************************
* Generate input according twitter bootsrap rules *
**************************************************@
<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {alert alert-error}">
    <label for="@elements.id"><strong>@elements.label</strong> <small> @MyMessages.get(elements.infos.mkString(""))</small></label>

@if(elements.args.containsKey('_iconcls)){
<div class="input-prepend">

<span class="add-on">
    <i class="@elements.args.get('_iconcls) icon-size"></i>
</span>

    @elements.input

    <span class="help-block error small"><small>@MyMessages.get(elements.errors.mkString("; "))</small></span> 
</div>
}else{
    @if(elements.args.containsKey('_prependedInput)){
<div class="input-prepend">

<span class="add-on">
    @elements.args.get('_prependedInput)
</span>

    @elements.input

    <span class="help-block error small"><small>@elements.errors.mkString("; ")</small></span> 
</div>
    }else{
        @elements.input
        <span class="help-block error small"><small>@elements.errors.mkString("; ")</small></span> 
    }
}
```